# React Js ERROR "When i install react js it show me an error "

Tags: reactjs

**Issue in downloading reactJs app**
When i run this code `create-react-app firstreactproject` i meet an error like this :

[image]

Anyone can help to resolve this error.

Comment: Can show us content of your package.json file ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the app in `system32` folder. Which belongs to OS. It might not let it create any project. Rather i would suggest you to create this project outside `windows` folder like in your user's directory.

Try with this:

1. Create a folder in your user's directory `Projects`.
2. Navigate to this folder `cd Projects`.
3. Run the command here `C:\Users\...\Projects> create-react-app firstreactproject`.

Hopefully it can create the project for you.